# Mockito mock return null

Tags: java, mockito

I have this code, but it doesnt work. excelGenerationService.generateExcel allways return null. Im completely stuck with this problem. Can someone help me? Note that sxssfWorkbook is not null.

```
SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = getTestExcelFile();
doReturn(sxssfWorkbook).when(excelGenerationService).generateExcel(any(ReportingTemplate.class), anyList(), anyList(), anyList(), anyString(), anyString(), anyBoolean(), anyBoolean(), anyString(), anyBoolean());
```

Comment: verify that the parameters in the stub (the doReturn line) match the parameters you use in the test.

Answer (score 0):

- Use @InjectMocks and @Spy Annotation on the service so that you have a mock object

  @InjectMocks
  @Spy
  ExcelGenerationService excelGenerationService;
- generateExcel(any(ReportingTemplate.class)), Change this to any(), you might have received a mock object here.

EDIT 1:
Replace @Mock with @InjectMocks and @Spy

Comment: I have "@Mock" annotation on ExcelGeneration service  "@Mock"
    private ExcelGenerationService excelGenerationService;

Comment: I tried to change it to any(), but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that anyString() dont match with null value. I set parameter of method to string from null and now its running smoothly.

Also you can use public static  T nullable(Class clazz).